# Can´t install packages even after changing library path

Tags: r, error-handling, package, tidyverse

I tried to install the package "tidyverse" recently. It didn´t work as my default library is apparently leading into a OneDrive file. I´ve tried changing it with help of the following website (https://www.accelebrate.com/library/how-to-articles/r-rstudio-library), more precisely I did this:

```
> setwd("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library")

> myPaths <- .libPaths()

> myPaths <- c(myPaths, "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library")

> .libPaths(myPaths)
```

but the environment still showed the old libPath.
When trying to install the package I still get the error:

unable to translate 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive - Universit<U+FFFD>t Potsdam/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.1' to native encoding
Error in install.packages : unable to translate 'C:\Users\laura\OneDrive - Universit<U+FFFD>t Potsdam\Dokumente\R\win-library\4.1' to native encoding

I´m a Beginner. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would put the path you want *first*, not last. That is, you want `myPaths <- c("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library", myPaths)` (in the opposite order)

Comment: Also, if you're running this code multiple times, you might want to throw a `unique()` in there so you don't end up with repetitive libraries. `myPaths <- unique(c("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library", myPaths))`

Comment: that helped, I can see in my environment now my desired path chr [1:3] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library" "C:/Users/laura/OneDrive - Universit<U+FFFD>t Potsdam/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.1"

Comment: the latter path "C:/Users/laura/OneDrive - Universit<U+FFFD>t Potsdam/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.1" is the one that isn´t working/ the one I want to remove, how do I do that?

Comment: To keep just the first one you could run directly `.libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library")`

Comment: thx so much! It almost worked. R tells me now : cannot create dir 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\library\file4ca076226447', reason 'Permission denied'
Error in install.packages : unable to create temporary directory ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\library\file4ca076226447’
>  Any idea what to do now?